# Linq select same id and remove other

Tags: c#, list, linq, where-clause, linq-group

[image: List]
I need to filter this list.
I just want to have those person that have the same SalId and those must be at least two.

How do I do it?

Comment: see [group by clause](http://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/bb384063.aspx) and `select` where count in group >= 2

Answer (score 9, accepted):

```
var dupSalIdPersons = persons
  .GroupBy(p => p.SalId)
  .Where(g => g.Count() >= 2)
  .SelectMany(g =>  g);
```

Comment: tim, i'm sure you've got a timemachine going there. speedy responese  -+1

Comment: @user1083647: note that you can use `.Select(g => g.ToList()).ToList();` instead of `.SelectMany(g =>  g);` if you want a `List<List<Person>>` instead where each list contains all duplicate persons. My approach above flattens all persons into a single collection which is currently unordered.

Comment: @TimSchmelter What would happen if there's `.Select(g =>  g.First()).ToList();` instead of  `SelectMany(g => g);` because I saw many ppl are working with `.First()).ToList()` when they want to get rid of duplicates columns

Comment: @Roxy'Pro: that's a completly different requirement. This question didnt want to remove duplicates, Don Juan wanted to list all persns with at least two equal `SalId`. The `g.First()` approach removes those duplicates whereas mine approach above lists them.